# What does Redis count as "changed" when persisting?

Tags: c#, redis

I'm developing an application in C# with Redis and we need to operate every 5 seconds on a key and write it back.

Our application has to run on a very small device with a not-so-durable SD card (IoT) and so performing a lot of writes all the time could become a problem in the future.

We start Redis in a docker container with:

```
redis-server --save 60 1 --loglevel warning
```

The value we want to write will be the same as we read it before in probably 99.9% (and thats actually correct, not an overestimation) of cases.

The order of operation is:

1. Fetch current value of the object (it's a C# object we're saving)
2. Do some stuff which MAY update the object in very rare cases
3. Write the object back

Since using WATCH in C# is not possible but we need to make sure we're atomic we need to write the object all the time back to Redis.

My question is:

**What does Redis persistence count as "changed"? Is it the SET itself or does it only count when there is an actual update?**

We serialize / deserialize using Newtonsoft JsonConvert, so same object will result in the same string.

Answer (score 0):

So here's the answer.

I tried it out with a fresh instance of Redis and sadly, Redis counts every SET, even if it is with the already existing value, as a change in the data and therefore will perform the snapshot.